# In the context of linear regression with two parameters, how do I show $\det(\mathbf{X}^\text{T}\mathbf{X} )\ne 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Let $\mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} b_0 \\ b_1\\ \end{bmatrix} $ and $\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_{11} \\ 1 & x_{21} \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_{n1} \end{bmatrix}$

Then

$\mathbf{X}^\text{T}\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}n&\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i1} \\ \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i1} & \sum_{i=1}^n x^2_{i1}\end{bmatrix}$

So therefore

$\det(\mathbf{X}^\text{T}\mathbf{X} ) = n \sum_{i=1}^n x^2_{i1} - (\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i1})^2$

**My Question**

I am pretty sure for this problem $\det(\mathbf{X}^\text{T}\mathbf{X} ) \ne 0$. But if I let each $x_{i1} = 0$ for all $i$, then $\det(\mathbf{X}^\text{T}\mathbf{X} )=0$. This doesn't match what I think I should get. How do I show that $\det(\mathbf{X}^\text{T}\mathbf{X} )\ne 0$

Comment: Why do you think the determinant must be zero? Because you invert the matrix for covariance?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, if $x_{i1}=0$ for all $i$, $X^T X$ won't be invertible. This is because $X$ has rank 1 in this case.

In a real regression problem, you will have at least one of the $x_{i1}$'s be different from the others (so the second column is not simply a scaled version of the first column), which will give $X^T X$ to be full rank and have non-zero determinant.

Comment: Could there be multiple $x_{i1}$ not equal to zero but $\det(X^TX) = 0$?

Comment: Yes. Any constant second column will give det 0

Comment: Take a moment to think of what the problem would mean if the second column was constant (draw a picture of the points involved).